# What is a generic triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles

I think the question speaks for itself.  I came across this term in one exercise, but am not sure what it is.

The definition my textbook gives is a triangle where the three vertices are free.  I am not sure what vertices being free mean either so am confused.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you quote the complete exercise from the book?

Comment: @littleO  Draw a generic triangle (where all vertices are free), then find the incenter.

Comment: I'd guess it means draw a scalene triangle but I could be wrong.

Comment: A free vertex is like a free variable, but for spatial points. A free variable acts like a placeholder for which you are **free** to substitute any value you like.

Comment: @DavidH So a triangle with free vertices could be any kind of triangle?

Comment: @PaulFilch precisely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic triangle is a triangle is a triangle which can be considered as a placeholder for any triangle at all. If you are using algebra, this usually means assuming unknown variables for corner coordinates or whatever you use to describe it. When doing a construction, you should start with a triangle with no special properties (i.e. no equal angles, no equal edge lengths, and so on) but also ensure that a triangle *with* such special properties could be used the same way.